# I need plugin to support designing & editing image in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, responsive-design, editing

Need plugin support design image with allow to add another image to selected image.
Or any site api support this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

here are some of the packages for image editing, explore them if it can fit your purpose.

[image_editor_pro](https://pub.dev/packages/image_editor_pro/example)

[image_editor](https://pub.dev/packages/image_editor)

[fluttercandies](https://github.com/fluttercandies/extended_image)